# Behaviour of append and enumerate - when appending to list, can I return values in an order other than they way they are appended?

Tags: python, list, append, enumerate

I am creating a list containing the indices of the lowest three numbers in a separate list (excluding 0 - this is part of a knn function).

```
x = [0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1]
y = []

for index, item in enumerate(x):
    if 0 < item < 4:
        y.append(index)
print y

Out: [5, 7, 9]
```

I would expect `y` to equal `[9, 5, 7]`, but the list is returned sorted. While this is probably ok for what I'm doing - how can I return the indices in the order they are appended?

Update: As lots of people quickly pointed out, I'm an idiot, what I mean to ask is, how can I return y to equal `[9,5,7]`, instead of returning the indices in the order they are appended?

Comment: Why do you expect to get `[9, 5, 7]`?  What order do you think you are appending the indices in?

Comment: `[9, 5, 7]` looks like the indices of the items which satisfy the inequality, sorted by the values of the corresponding items (item is 1 at index 9, then 2 at index 5, then 3 at index 7).

Comment: Ah yes sorry! Brain malfunction for a minute there - what I'm actually after is how to return y so is IS ordered like `[9,5,7]`. Will edit for clarity.

Comment: Right, because ideally you want the indices of the knn's in order of "nearness"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` iterates over the list from beginning to end.  The first index is 0.  So that means the first index matching your criteria is 5, then 7, then 9.  It's not clear why, for instance, you think 9 would be the first item appended; that is the last item in `x`, so it will be reached last in the iteration and will wind up last in `y`.

If you want the indices in the order of the values, you can't achieve that just by looking at the indices in their existing order.  You need to somehow track the relative magnitudes of the actual elements.  One possibility is:

```
>>> sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda ix: x[ix])
[0, 9, 5, 7, 8, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2]
```

You can subset this with `[1:4]` if you want to get the 2nd to 4th biggest elements:

```
>>> sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda ix: x[ix])[1:4]
[9, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
y.append(index)
```

you are adding the index (or location) of the element in the list, so the returned list is actually in the order in which you appended them.

`enumerate` returns a list of tuples with indices and the corresponding element. besides, the only way your program would return `[9, 5, 7]` is if it returned the indices of the 3 smallest values in your list, in order.